# Game working on Win7 but not Vista?

Tags: c#, windows-7, xna, windows-vista, inno-setup

I've been developing a game and after each update I send my friend a setup.exe to use I made with Inno Setup. It's always worked fine up until now. He is able to instal the game but when he runs the .exe he gets "Game has stopped working". While it works fine for me after installing. The only thing I can think of that could of caused this was I added saving and loading using storage containers. I choose the location to save in with:

```
 asyncResult = StorageDevice.BeginShowSelector(playerIndex, null, null);

 storageDevice = StorageDevice.EndShowSelector(asyncResult);

 asyncResult = storageDevice.BeginOpenContainer("Game1StorageContainer", null, null);
```

This places the file in: Desktop\Libraries\Documents\SavedGames\Game\Game1StorageContainer\Player1\

This is a vague question but maybe someone has an idea?

:: UPDATE ::

Ok, I've had my friend reinstall the XNA Runtime, same problem.

There are no files in his minidump folder, even with hidden folders shown.

However I have a windows error log here:

```
 Application: My Game.exe
 Framework Version: v4.0.30319
 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
 Exception Info:Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.GamerServicesNotAvailableException
 Stack:
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.KernelMethods+ProxyProcess..ctor(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.UserPacketBuffer)
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.KernelMethods.Initialize(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.UserPacketBuffer)
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.GamerServicesDispatcher.Initialize(System.IServiceProvider)
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.GamerServicesComponent.Initialize()
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize()
    at My_Game.Game1.Initialize()
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean)
    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
    at My_Game.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

So, It crashed at Game1.Initialize();, which contains:

```
 protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        this.graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        this.graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

So surely it is the base.Initialize();, which I'm guessing is because I've included some new libraries from the framework. So I have no idea what to do, the previous version of my game works fine for him.

Someone have any idea what I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Show more details – especially Message, type and stack trace – in a global exception handler. Alternatively (and better, but requires more work from your friend) capture a process dump on exception. See the recent C9 series on production debugging for more on getting and using dumps: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment/Diagnosing-Application-Issues-01

Comment: So this is not InnoSetup related I guess...

Comment: Log and dump and then log something more, try-catch-finally everything, then tell your friend to send whatever comes out back to you. Or, debug on his rig.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does he have the [XNA Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914) installed?
2. Check the Windows Event Log, it should have a detailed entry for the crash
3. When an application crashes, a [minidump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263) is created. You should be able to load this into visual studio and see where it crashed.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my first post with some new information, do you have any idea what I could do?